# icy-metaint parsing

Tags: shoutcast, internet-radio

I had some old java code of mine, which reads a Shoutcast stream and parses the "icy-metaint" value from the data. A new stream did not work, and I realised that the "icy-metaint" was in the http header variables instead. Why does this stream contain the info in the header? New Shoutcast standard? It works, but I need an explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has always been in the header, and was never in the data.  The data starts right off with MP3 stream data, and always has, all the way back to the 90s.